# How to increase delay after which ReSharper navigation starts showing results?

Tags: resharper

When I use ctrl+shift+t and start typing, R# starts showing results immediately. This is causing performance issues for me (large project + remote desktop). Is there a way to increase the delay?

Comment: No. If you're seeing performance issues here, try profiling from the ReSharper → Help menu. This will send a snapshot to JetBrains who can investigate.

Comment: Not exactly an answer to this question, but I've found the solution to the performance issues I've been experiencing when using Resharper over remote desktop. I simply changed the color depth setting to 16 bit instead of 32 bit in RDP settings and the performance increased drastically.